# Filtering duplicates when asking questions

Tags: feature-request, tags, duplicate-questions, filtering

When I ask questions, I always look through the "Questions that may already have your answer" box to be sure that I'm not about to post a duplicate. I've started to work with different platforms and I would like to have filtering on the duplicate questions box so I can find questions that I may be duplicating in a much easier fashion.

For example, I just [posted a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11561460/place-pushpin-on-single-click) about mouse clicks and Bing Maps, specifically in the context of WPF and C#. However, the duplicate questions box is showing questions that refer to Windows Phone and even [my own previous question about Bing Maps and Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11251401/adding-click-event-listener-to-pushpin/11457707#11457707). While this may or may not be a significant difference, how I do something in Android could be wildly different than how I do it with WPF. Filtering the duplicate questions box would remove these unhelpful duplicate suggestions and make  it easier to find an actual duplicate.

Is it possible that we could filter the duplicate questions box in accordance to what tags you've selected for your question?

Comment: I bet this has been requested before, but regardless we really need this feature. Maybe if we had this feature you would have seen the duplicate ;P

Comment: I like the idea of filtering, but I think the unfiltered list should be displayed first along with a list of tags (union of the tags specified for each question - not your tags).  The tags listed could be used to filter the list of possible dups.  This would be sure that all possible dups are displayed but would let you easily filter down to your areas of interest.

Comment: I guess that if the tags input area was more to the top those could be used to filter the possible duplicates? Not sure if there's been a meta question yet on (re)positioning that input though.

Comment: @Jeroen I'll agree that the current layout for tagging doesn't make this request very effective or useful.

Comment: Still, I've put my suggestion into an answer. Maybe it'll inspire others to write bigger & better answers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Agreed, +1 for this issue. I'm hoping others will come up with bigger and better answers, but here's a small suggestion that may help at least a bit, and may be worth it if it's easy to implement.

---

***TL;DR Version:*** please use tags in calculating weight for search results.

---

Consider the following example:

[image: Example of issue described below]

Surely the `WPF` tag could be used in suggesting duplicates in some way, and push those pesky CSS results away?

Note: I appreciate that **the location of the tags input may not be optimal** for my suggestion, but changing the location of that input probably has its own complications. In any case I'd think that *using tags in filtering the possible duplicates* won't *hurt* anyone and may *help a bit* for those that know of the feature and/or (like me) tend to write down a few tags before starting the question text.